# What does this command-line do?

Tags: shell

Please explain this in ways that I can understand:

```
ps ax >mytemp; more <mytemp … same as … ps ax | more
cat mytemp | grep barrymp … same as … ps ax | grep “barrymp”
```

Comment: Please ask a single thing in a question.

Comment: Come on. A close vote after 5 minutes, give the guy a chance to explain what he really wants.

Comment: My sense of what they're getting at is that these are probably lecture notes or something and Deven just doesn't understand what the professor is trying to communicate.

Comment: Hey! I'm new at this stuff. Calm down. Why you gotta be so hard on me. I came here for help, didn't I?

Answer (score 3):

Taking it one line at a time, splitting each line in half:

```
ps ax >mytemp; more <mytemp
```

Takes the output of `ps ax` and puts it into a file called `mytemp`. The semi-colon marks the beginning of a separate command on the same line. The second command takes the contents of `mytemp` and feeds them into `more` (a pager that displays the file screen-by-screen). Your notes then say this is the same as `ps ax | more` which is true except it doesn't create a temporary `mytemp` file. Both effectively take the output of `ps ax` and eventually make it the standard input for `more`

Second line:

```
cat mytemp | grep barrymp
```

Prints the contents of a file called `mytemp` to stdout which is then redirected to the standard input for the `grep` command which has been given `barrymp` to filter the output from.

The notes then say it's the same as `ps ax | grep "barrymp"`. I'm assuming this is because it's supposed to be the same `mytemp` from the first line. The second half of that line likewise skips the temporary file and just goes straight to redirecting the command output to the pipe to grep.

Tried to break it down as much as I could think to, let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: What does "ax" stand for? And what does the command line output to?

Comment: You can check the man page (via `man ps`) for a full description but basically it's BSD syntax for "All Executing processes" meaning it looks at all users, regardless of TTY status of the program.

Comment: The commands ultimately output to the Shell's standard output, but the various routes they take to get there are detailed in the answer above.

Comment: @Deven the best way for you to understand is to just run each of these commands separately. Just run `ps ax` alone, then `ps ax > mytemp` and look at the contents of `mytemp` (use `cat mytemp`) and so on. You should also read a short command line primer, [this one](http://lifehacker.com/5633909/who-needs-a-mouse-learn-to-use-the-command-line-for-almost-anything) for example.

Comment: One other difference worth noting is that redirecting `ps ax` to a file is effectively taking a snapshot of the process table as it was at that moment in time - every time you search that file with grep it will search the same data.  By contrast, `ps ax | grep barrymp` will always search the *current* process table, which will be different every time you run it.